Install ubuntu on Microsoft Surface Go3
Is it possible to install Ubuntu 24.04 on Microsoft Surface Go3 ? Instead of Windows.

Yes. After installing Ubuntu, touchscreen and sound may not work, but this answer tells you how to fix all of them. Note that camera support is work in progress for your device, and hibernate does not work yet.

This question is similar to: How to make touchscreen Microsoft Surface devices running Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
